# Send extra parameters to the server with javascript libraries to upload files

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, file-upload, laravel-5.1

Hi I've searched in bower packages with upload keyword: 
http://bower.io/search/?q=upload

I found these interesting dropzone, fine-uploader, Resumable.js, flow.js, ng-flow
But I've noticed that this kind of libraries only post the file, I have not found a callback or method to post additional info with the file, like this

```
{"categoryid":"1", "metadata":"metadata of the file"}
```

is there a way to do that with these libraries?, how to get the metadata at server side?.
I'm working with laravel making the rest api and angularjs making the client.

Comment: Are you really asking someone to check the docs for all those packages for you? You'll get better responses if you post code that gives you _specific_ problems.

Comment: The English is not my native language, but I'm sure in this question I'm not asking anyone to check the documents of anything at all, I already did that, I'm asking for people that already work with these libraries if they know if that feature is available in any of these libraries. 

Please do not confuse the context of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a powerful file upload package for Angular. [Check it out here](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload). It can do exactly what you are looking to do and more.

Comment: As you said, this library does exactly what I need. thanks

Answer (score 2):

in front end:

```
var r = new Resumable({
    target: 'serverfile.php',
    query: { addtional_info : 'your_value' }
});
```

in back end: (php)

```
<?php
$my_addtional_val = $_POST['addtional_info'];
 ...
?>
```

Comment: is it possible add parameter after Resumable initialized?